# Magento 2 Add Image to product media gallery

Tags: php, magento2, media

I am using bacon-qr-code library to generate a png file containing the QR code of the product info, it is generated and i am using `$product->addImageToMediaGallery()` function, which creates a folder called  `tmp` under `pub/media` folder and the rest of the folder structure inside it is same as `catalog/1/2/3/file.png`, but when i try to save the product model, the browser just displays this message `The connection was reset`,

I am doing this on `catalog_product_load_after` event.

Also i will need to check if the qr code for the product already exists or not, there is a column called `label` in the table row, i am going to use it to check the condition, but i could not find any method to add the image along with other attributes.

Any Help will be appreciated